# How to match a string pattern in a string contained in array

Tags: c#, .net

I need to check if a string pattern in the array is contained in a string.
I am using the following code but it matches the exact string contained in the array not the pattern so the following will fail. 
How can I do this?

```
String[] stringArrayToBlock = { "#", "/", "string1:", "string2" };
String SearchString = "String1:sdfsfsdf";

 if (stringArrayToBlock.Contains(SearchString.Trim().ToLower()))
 { 
   //Do work
 }
```

Comment: isn't the condition the other way around?

Comment: by 'string pattern' you mean like '12345',so it should locate all strings which have 5 numbers ?

Comment: well it works this way because I need to check If the string in the array matches the string. But now that I am thinking of it I guess it is the same

Comment: Isn't this a regex issue then?

Comment: well I don't know how to use regex to work this around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should do it vice versa. Besides, if you're open to LINQ, [Enumerable.Any Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx) is very handy:

```
string[] stringArrayToBlock = { "#", "/", "string1:", "string2" };
string SearchString = "String1:sdfsfsdf";
string lowerCaseString = SearchString.Trim().ToLower();
if (stringArrayToBlock.Any(s => lowerCaseString.Contains(s)))    
{
    //Do work
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the LINQ `Any()` method to determine if any of the elements of the array satisfy the condition. 
The `Contains` method used here is that of `string`, not of `Array`.

```
String[] stringArrayToBlock = { "#", "/", "string1:", "string2" };
String SearchString = "String1:sdfsfsdf";

 if (stringArrayToBlock.Any(s => SearchString.Trim().ToLower().Contains(s)))
 { 
     //Do work
 }
```

Comment: I'll quote Bryan Hong: _isn't the condition the other way around?_

Comment: I think the question is regarding locating 'string pattern' not the 'exact string'

Comment: yes I mention that I am looking for the string pattern, anyways, thank you

Comment: Sorry. Missed that part. Why am I getting upvotes? It's obviously wrong :)